# Does intermittent fasting (e.g., time-restricted) without calorie reduction/increase make it easier or more difficult to gain muscles when exercising?

Tags: exercise, muscle-gain, intermittent-fasting

Does intermittent fasting (e.g., time-restricted such as 16-hour fasting and 8-hour eating windows) without calorie reduction/increase  make it easier or more difficult to gain muscles when exercising?

All the studies I've seen so far such as {1} use an intermittent fasting that reduce the calorie intake, which introduces a bias when    comparing intermittent fasting and non-intermittent fasting.

---

Answers to comments:

- Comment 1: "There’s nothing anabolic about not eating." – JustSnilloc ↵ Jan 6 at 3:12
- Reply to comment 1: Quote from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30696848's abstract: "anabolism stimulated by fasting"

---

References:

- {1} Tinsley, Grant M., Jeffrey S. Forsse, Natalie K. Butler, Antonio Paoli, Annie A. Bane, Paul M. La Bounty, Grant B. Morgan, and Peter W. Grandjean. "Time-restricted feeding in young men performing resistance training: A randomized controlled trial." European journal of sport science 17, no. 2 (2017): 200-207. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27550719

Comment: There’s nothing anabolic about not eating.

Comment: @JustSnilloc From https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30696848's abstract: "anabolism stimulated by fasting"

Comment: @FrankDernoncourt - I don't have access to the full study, could you perhaps clarify what they are talking about there because it doesn't seem clear to me. Also, your quoting of that section doesn't even make sense because there is a soft pause in the sentence after anabolism.